# How to host WCF in Windows Services or NT services?

Tags: windows, wcf

Is any Idea how can we host WCF service to windows service????

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Follow the documentation.

Seriouosly. The term is "self hosting wcf"

First item in google for me points to.

https://uat-server-ca.tools.intranet.db.com/download/3241471

Titel: How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Application

Has code samples, btw.

Answer (score 1):

I got My answer

here is what I want:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFMultipleHosting.aspx

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has examples for Self Hosting in a [managed Windows (NT) Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069) as well as Self Hosting in a [Managed Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758).